# How to host a MERN stack project on GoDaddy

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, hosting, web-hosting

I dev community there my problem is how to deploy a website.

The real problem is:-

I've a React web app with monogdb Atlas as Databse
I'm also having a domain on GoDaddy so how do I combine all these things to get my website live

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use Godday as a server also then you need a paid plan Hosting

```
Launch - Web Hosting Plus
```

with VPS that only Supports MERN stack

Or you can use free hosting https://dashboard.render.com/ and link monogoDb on monogoDB site

After all setup from render hosting settings `Custom Domain` you can connect your godaddy domain free off cost

and this hosting has sleep time sometimes it works slow